# Unable to chat. "fixed font" button shown

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow, chat

I'm unable to chat in stack overflow chat room.

When I type and hit enter , it always shows 'fixed font" button.

If I hit `Send`, the messages will not display in chat.

I'm using Safari Version 6.0.2 (7536.26.17) with bluetooth keyboard. Mac OSX 10.7.5

Here is the screen shot

[image]

Comment: The result being what, exactly?

Comment: Browser, browser version?

Comment: Safari Version 6.0.2 (7536.26.17) with blutooth keyboard..

Comment: What you mean exactly by "fixed font button" showing? Your report is not really clear.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: please look at the screenshot posted along with the question. You can see the exact screen(with a fixed font button near the upload and cursor came to middle of the chat box)...

Comment: @Ramshad The screen shot is clear, but the meaning is not.  What significance does this button have in this regard?

Comment: @Daedalus: I have edited.. is it make sense ?

Comment: No, still no sense and I don't get what is wrong. You never explained what is "fix font button".

Comment: When I type and hit enter ,it shows same as the screen shot... the chat window stays same, one extra button appeared next to the upload button as fixed font. I dont know what it do.. thats it..

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd  The fixed font button appears when you have more than one line in your chat messages.  It is used to keep code indentation.  The OP is saying that when he presses <enter> the fixed font button appears and his message doesn't get sent.

Comment: Maybe you have sticky keys turned on?  See this to check if sticky keys is enabled: http://etc.usf.edu/techease/4all/input-devices/what-are-sticky-keys/

Comment: thnks for the responds. sticky keys is off...

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that your <kbd>⇑</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> got stuck.

I can't reproduce as-is, but if I hold my shift key down, when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I am actually pressing<kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>Enter</kbd> which has the effect of inserting a blank line in the message input box.

This in turn makes the message multi-line and this makes the "fixed font" button appear. This is also confirmed by your screenshot:

[image]

Comment: yup.. however, i can chat fine through mozilla firefox browser.So  is there any specific keyboard settings option for Safari browser ? I think, there is only one settings for Keyboard which is available in common preference. am I right ?